# Validating a color in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, validation, colors

I construct some xaml in a template class and I need a rectangle to have a Fill property set to something coming from a textbox filled by the end user. Therefore I need to validate that the value is convertable to a Brush object before outputting the xaml. Otherwise, if the value is not a valid color (named or not) I get following : Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Invalid XAML for control 'sldivparent'. [] (line 6, col 412): Failed to create a 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' from the text 'NotValidColorValue'. Obviously, I don't want that and in case of invalid value I just want it to be White.

So how could I make sure 'NotValidColorValue' is a valid color value before proceeding?

Thanks

Edit for further clarification: 
I am using color picker, calling a YUI color picker from silverlight to be exact and its working fine. The thing is that a user can also type in a color (either #112233 or "Red") directly in the textbox and that needs to be valid or display white if invalid. I don't want 
to go into the whole manual check of color names, so ideally I'd like to attempt to create an object of some type (maybe some Brush derivative) using whatever user has typed in and if that doesn't succeed I'd know the color value was invalid and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
Did some more thinking about this problem. You can just bind the value :) This will both validate the color and set it. An invalid value will use the FallbackValue White.

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=textBox,
                          Path=Text,
                          FallbackValue=White}"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox" Text="Green"/>
```

And if you need to have methods like IsColorValid and GetColorFromValue in code behind you can use Bindings there as well like this

```
private bool IsValidColor(string colorValue)
{
    if (colorValue == "White" || colorValue == "#FFF" || colorValue == "#FFFF" ||
        colorValue == "#FFFFFF" || colorValue == "#FFFFFFFF")
    {
        return true;
    }
    Brush fallbackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    Rectangle validationRectangle = new Rectangle();
    Binding validationBinding = new Binding();
    validationBinding.Source = colorValue;
    validationBinding.FallbackValue = fallbackBrush;
    validationRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, validationBinding);
    if (validationRectangle.Fill == fallbackBrush)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private Color GetColorFromValue(string colorValue)
{
    Rectangle validationRectangle = new Rectangle();
    Binding validationBinding = new Binding();
    validationBinding.Source = colorValue;
    validationBinding.FallbackValue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    validationRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, validationBinding);
    return ((SolidColorBrush)validationRectangle.Fill).Color;
}
```

Comment: that, sir, is what I call spot on! well and truly deserved points coming your way.

Comment: @danijels: Thanks :) Even scrgb text-values like `"sc# 1.0,0.5,0.8,0.0"` works with this approach. Removed the old part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want but if you want to validate `#11223344` values, use `Regex validation` using something like following pattern:

```
(^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}$|^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$|^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}$)
```

Now, if you want a user to type down a name of color, try using something like [`Color ComboBox`](http://silverlightips.net/2010/05/19/color-picker-combo-control-in-silverlight/) instead.

And finally, I would recommend using a [`ColorPicker`](http://secondstanza.com/2009/05/02/silverlight-color-picker-control/) above all. Its about providing a `Rich UI` after all.

Comment: user has to be able to type in both named color or #11223344. And I am  using a colorpicker, only not the silverlight one.

Comment: So, did you try the `regex` suggestion? You can also list all public static properties of type `Color` from `Colors` class using `Reflection` and store names in a list. Use above regex to match it with # pattern and also match it with the color name list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the `Brush` object with whatever the user enters. If it throws an exception, catch it and let the user know. Otherwise, it's a valid `Color`.

Comment: Brush is an abstract class and cannot be created. SolidColorBrush as one of the derived classes has no constructor that can take a string and use it to attempt to turn it into a color.

Comment: What is throwing the exception? Why can't you try/catch around that?